# Group values and merge on Pandas with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data on a csv:

```
c1    c2
1     2
1     3
3     4
3     5
4     6
```

What I need to do is to process that data and have the following output:

```
c1    c2
1     2,3
3     4,5
4     6
```

Is this possible with pandas?

Thanks

Comment: `2,3` is a list or string?

Comment: Just a string. Thanks

Comment: just do `df.groupby('c1')['c2'].apply(','.join)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first convert column `c2` to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) `join`. Last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df['c2'] = df['c2'].astype(str)
print df.groupby('c1')['c2'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
   c1   c2
0   1  2,3
1   3  4,5
2   4    6
```

If you need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print df
   c1  c2
0   1   2
1   1   3
2   1   2
3   1   3
4   3   4
5   3   5
6   4   6

df['c2'] = df['c2'].astype(str)
df = df.groupby('c1')['c2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.drop_duplicates())).reset_index()
print df
   c1   c2
0   1  2,3
1   3  4,5
2   4    6
```

If you need sort `DataFrame` by length of values in column `c2`, use [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html). Last you can [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `sort`:

```
print df
   c1  c2
0   1   4
1   1   5
2   4   6
3   2   7
4   2   3
5   2   2
6   2   3

df['c2'] = df['c2'].astype(str)
df = df.groupby('c1')['c2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.drop_duplicates())).reset_index()

df['sort'] = df['c2'].str.len()
df = df.sort_values('sort')
df = df.drop('sort',axis=1)
print df
   c1     c2
2   4      6
0   1    4,5
1   2  7,3,2

print df.reset_index(drop=True)
   c1     c2
0   4      6
1   1    4,5
2   2  7,3,2
```

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for! Just one more question. The "c2" columns could have repeated values giving me sometimes something like this "2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3". How can I get only unique values and not duplicates?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I am really new to Pandas. Is it possible to sort the dataframe by "c2" column by the amount of items on it? I understand that "c2" is a string now, so I suppose that I need to use something like `len(split(",", c2))` but I don't know how to apply that on the df